# GEE Process for deciding what pixels lie within a geometry

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, geometry, reducers

I am using image and collection reducers to extract mean values of several assets (for example, prism precipitation and pml2 ET) from within USGS watershed boundaries which I load in as geometries. I am generally extracting data at 1000m scale.

I am having no problem with this workflow, however I am wondering what GEE does to determine which pixels qualify as within the geometry? (Is it based on the centroid or edge or another calculation?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Weighted reducers (e.g. ee.Reducer.mean()): pixels are included if at
>   least (approximately) 0.5% of the pixel is in the region and the
>   image's mask is non-zero; their weight is the minimum of the image's
>   mask and the (approximate) fraction of the pixel covered by the
>   region.

Quoted straight from following GEE tutorial: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_region

Comment: Thank you so much, @korndog! Don't know how I missed that! I don't have enough reputation to officially upvote you on GIS stack overflow, but I will return and complete that task when I do. Thanks again!